# CERN LHCb leptoquarks and grand unified theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

Recent CERN LHCb experiment suggests possible [leptoquarks as new particles beyond the standard model *may* be discovered, with 3.1 $\sigma$ not the 5 $\sigma$ discovery](https://web.archive.org/web/20210324054334/https://physicsworld.com/a/has-a-new-particle-called-a-leptoquark-been-spotted-at-cern/).

What are the viable candidates of leptoquarks in the  beyond the standard model theory?

For example,

- in the $SU(5)$ grand unified theory, do we have the $X$ and $Y$ bosons as leptoquarks?
- in the $SO(10)$  grand unified theory, what are the possible leptoquarks?
- in the Pati-Salam grand unified theory, what are the possible leptoquarks?

What are the quantum numbers of their leptoquarks for the $SU(3), SU(2)$, $U(1)$ hypercharge, and $U(1)$ electric charge?

Comment: The experimental result is strictly an apparent violation of lepton universality.  There's a lot more things that could contribute to that besides leptoquarks—although leptoquarks are a easy explanation.

Comment: my answer here to  related questions   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/625223/breakthrough-at-the-large-hadron-collider-leptoquarks-skepticism/625305#625305  and   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/625312/march-2021-cern-discovery-what-would-be-the-properties-of-the-new-particle-forc/625513#625513

Comment: This pdg article answers your questions I think https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-leptoquark-quantum-numbers.pdf . Found by google "quantum numbers of leptoquarks "